# What type of variable, I need to define to insert following type of data (Spring-boot, Mongodb)

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-boot

**Data type:**

```
"label":"Price","type":"RANGE_SELECT","value":{"min":1,"max":100,"default":50} 

"label":"Wi-Fi","type":"SWITCH","value":"true"

"label":"Start Date","type":"DATE_PICKER","value":""
```

**The variable type I described as following:**

```
private String label;
private String type;
private List < String >  value;
```

**ERROR:**

> "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
>   `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT
>   token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 10]
>   (through reference chain:
>   com.mspace.uiservice.model.UiFilter[\"value\"])",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve the exact same data but some what similar to that via below entity, just create a class with one field

```
private Map<String,Object>  output;
```

Which will save all the values you put into the map as below:

```
"output":{
"label":"Price","type":"RANGE_SELECT","value":{"min":1,"max":100,"default":50} 
},
"output":{
"label":"Wi-Fi","type":"SWITCH","value":"true"
},
"output":{
"label":"Start Date","type":"DATE_PICKER","value":""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class like this

```
class Value {
  private Integer min;
  private Integer max;
  private Integer default;

//Getters, Setters
}
```

and change your pojo like this

```
private String label;
private String type;
private Value value;
```

If its a `[....]`, you can use List, but not for `{...}`

Comment: I'm not only need min max and default it may vary time to time. Also  it may be [....] or {.....} or Boolean

Comment: if you have different structures, then it is impossible(almost) to do. You have to stick to one format and write java classes based on that

Comment: But I need multiple format of object need to added to the database

Comment: then, you need to create multiple classes, you cannot do it in one java class.